# Post JSON object to php using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I am dynamically adding table rows by selecting options from dropdown and then I am trying to send html table rows to php function using ajax as array in json format. However php function does not print all rows in the console log, when I am submitting more than one row. I got the desired output like once or twice. I think I am missing something in the php function. Please check once. If anymore information about the code is required, let me know, I will update.

Javascript:

```
function storeClgValues() {
  var CollegeData= new Array();
  $('#collegetable tr').each(function(row, tr){
    CollegeData[row]={
        "college" : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
    }
  }); 
  CollegeData.shift();
  return CollegeData;
```

}

```
$('#submit').click(function() { 

 CollegeData=storeClgValues();
 CollegeData=$.toJSON(CollegeData);                     
 $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url: '<?php echo base_url();?>ajaxController/insertcollege',
       data: "CollegeData=" + CollegeData,
       success: function(msg) {
          console.log(CollegeData);
          console.log(msg);             
       }
  });
```

});

PHP function in AjaxController class:

```
 public function insertcollege()
 {   
    $data=array();
    $data=stripcslashes($_POST['CollegeData']);
    $data=json_decode($data, TRUE);
    //echo $data[0]['college'].'<br>';
    //echo $data[1]['college'].'<br>';
    if (is_array($data) || is_object($data))
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
            echo $item['college'].'<br>';
        }
    }
 }
```

Output in console in three tries:

```
[{"college":"College of Agriculture"}]
College of Agriculture

[{"college":"College of Agriculture"},{"college":"College of Business"}]
College of Agriculture 
College of Business

[{"college":"College of Agriculture"},{"college":"College of Business"}, {"college":"College of Comm & Educati"}]
<!--nothing gets printed-->
```

Comment: What does print_r or var_dump look like of $data after `$data=json_decode($data, TRUE);` when you've selected multiple compared to when you selected a single row?

Comment: Also what does print_r of $_POST look like when you've selected multiple rows?

Comment: This is really weird. I do not know what is causing the problem. But sometimes I get the output sometimes I do not get the response back. Print_r on $data printed like this.

    
     Array
     (
       [0] => Array
         (
            [college] => College of Agriculture
         )

     [1] => Array
         (
            [college] => College of Business
         )

     )

Comment: Do you have more than one element on the page where the id="submit"?

Comment: Or multiple rows where id="collegetable"? Also thinking might be a possibility that the Ajax post is happening before storClgValues has finished doing what it needs to do.

Comment: You may want to pass the ajax post through stireClgValues as a callback function http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp

Comment: Yes, collegetable is the id of the table where I am inserting a row or rows dynamically. When submit button is clicked, all the rows in the table are put in an array and that array is sent to the php function via ajax. So may be you are right one thing is happening before the other.

Comment: Okay no two elements should have the same id so you give them either a unique id e.g collegetable-1 or give then a class

Answer (score 1):

Try like this...

```
<?php
$json = '[{"college":"College of Agriculture"},{"college":"College of Business"}, {"college":"College of Comm & Educati"}]';
$data = json_decode($json,TRUE);
//print_r($data);
if (is_array($data) || is_object($data))
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
            $output[]=$item['college'].'<br>';
        }
    }
echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

OR

```
<?php
$json = '[{"college":"College of Agriculture"},{"college":"College of Business"}, {"college":"College of Comm & Educati"}]';
$data = json_decode($json,TRUE);
//print_r($data);
if (is_array($data) || is_object($data))
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
        foreach($item as $value){
            $output[] = $value."</br>";
        }
    }
}   
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sometimes I get the output sometimes I do not. I do not know what is causing the problem,